# vb code for selecting the 1st empty cell in column a of a word table

Tags: vba, select, ms-word, cell

I have been trying to get some code to automatically select the 1st empty cell in column A of a word table I have tried using examples of previous questions but not all of them wok and others just give a message box answer of the row and column. I have macros that input data into the table then sect the next row down in column A. But if my cursor isn't in the right place, ie, Column A and next empty cell then the data is written out of alignment column wise and often row wise.
one macro inserts time in the cell where ever the cursor is.
. I would like to select the the 1st empty cell in column A then enter the time maccro.

```
Selection.InsertDateTime DateTimeFormat:="HH:mm", InsertAsField:=False, _
        DateLanguage:=wdEnglishUK, CalendarType:=wdCalendarWestern, _
        InsertAsFullWidth:=False
```

Thankyou in advance
Regards jrfmps

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong but there is no direct way to find the **1st** empty cell in a specific column of a word table. You will have to loop as shown below.

**Code:**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim tbl As Table
    Dim aCell As Cell
    Dim aCol As Column
    
    '~~> Set this to the relevant table
    Set tbl = ActiveDocument.Tables(1)
    
    '~~> This is set for Col 1 (A)
    Set aCol = tbl.Columns(1)
    
    '~~> loop through cell in Col 1
    For Each aCell In aCol.Cells
        If aCell.Range.Text = Chr(13) & Chr(7) Then
            MsgBox "Cells (" & aCell.RowIndex & "," & aCell.ColumnIndex & ") is empty"
            Exit For
        End If
    Next aCell
End Sub
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

Avoid the use of `Selection`. Work directly with object(s). Here is how you can adapt your code to the above code...

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim tbl As Table
    Dim aCell As Cell
    Dim aCol As Column
    Dim rng As Range
    
    '~~> Set this to the relevant table
    Set tbl = ActiveDocument.Tables(1)
    
    '~~> This is set for Col 1 (A)
    Set aCol = tbl.Columns(1)
    
    '~~> loop through cell in Col 1
    For Each aCell In aCol.Cells
        If aCell.Range.Text = Chr(13) & Chr(7) Then
            MsgBox "Cells (" & aCell.RowIndex & "," & aCell.ColumnIndex & ") is empty"
            
            Set rng = tbl.Cell(aCell.RowIndex, aCell.ColumnIndex).Range
            
            rng.Collapse wdCollapseStart
            
            rng.InsertDateTime DateTimeFormat:="HH:mm", _
                               InsertAsField:=False, _
                               DateLanguage:=wdEnglishUK, _
                               CalendarType:=wdCalendarWestern, _
                               InsertAsFullWidth:=False
            Exit For
        End If
    Next aCell
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Siddharth. That has helped greatly. I now find another problem. I have a header table and below that is the table I want to use. Your code selects the 1st table  and I need to use the 2nd. This is a table of events as they happen in real time. How do I select the 2nd table please. Regards jrfmps

Comment: I have just realised that what I need is that the cell should be selected and made the active cell as all the inputs are relevant to that one. i.e. Time is inserted into the A column and then on the same row next column data is added and so on across the table. I can work out the rest I just can't seem to make the next empty cell in column A the active cell so I can reference from there.

Comment: You do not need to select it. That is the whole point. `Time is inserted into the A column and then on the same row next column data is added and so on across the table.` You already have the row number. simple work with that. `Set rng = tbl.Cell(aCell.RowIndex, aCell.ColumnIndex + 1 ).Range` will be the adjacent cell to it and so on.

Comment: Hi Siddharth, Yes your right I did have all the info i needed. Thank you. I did need to do a bit more for what I needed exactly but what you gave me more than enough to get what I wanted. I love this site with people like you who are so generous with your Knowledge.